# ArrayAdapter for country flag and image spinner slowing view down

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have the following class:

```
    private class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    CountryAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomDropdown(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    View getCustomDropdown(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DropViewHolder dropViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            dropViewHolder = new DropViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_spinner_row, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(dropViewHolder);
            dropViewHolder.label = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_countryNameRow);
            dropViewHolder.icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_countryFlagRow);
        } else {
            dropViewHolder = (DropViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        dropViewHolder.label.setText(String.format("%s (+%s)", countryNameList.get(position), countryList.optJSONObject(position).optString("phoneCountryCode")));

        String flagPath = "flag_" + countryList.optJSONObject(position).optString("countryCode").toLowerCase();
        dropViewHolder.icon.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(flagPath, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        return convertView;
    }

    View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_spinner_row_dropdown, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_countryFlagRow);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String flagPath = "flag_" + countryList.optJSONObject(position).optString("countryCode").toLowerCase();            viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(flagPath, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class DropViewHolder {
        TextView label;
        AdapterImageView icon;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        AdapterImageView icon;
    }
}
```

I think it complies with all the standards for an ArrayAdapter, reusing views etc. However when opening the keyboard, the view redraws and there is significant lag on button positioning updating.

Is there anything glaringly obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: for extra clarity, `AdapterImageView` is just a class that extends `ImageView` and overrides `requestLayout` without calling super to prevent expensive redraws.

EDIT2: By contrast, this piece of code, which is older and in theory worse performing, does not lag the UI.

```
 public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CountryAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_spinner_row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_countryNameRow);
        label.setText(countryNameList.get(position).toString());


        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_countryFlagRow);
        String flagPath = "flag_" + countryList.optJSONObject(position).optString("countryCode").toLowerCase();

        icon.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(flagPath, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Three things in your code look like they _could_ be slow. (1) accessing the json to get the flag's country name every time, (2) using `getResources().getIdentifier()` instead of accessing `R.drawable.foo` directly, and (3) setting the image to the image view. Try timing each of these actions and see if any take more than a millisecond.

Comment: Hi @BenP. thanks for your pointers, i will make sure to try. I've also updated the question to provide an older and in theory less efficient piece of code, however, that one does not cause the UI to lag...

Comment: Hm. That makes it sound like `AdapterImageView` might be the culprit. Perhaps the custom code you've written has some side-effects you didn't expect.

Comment: Haha no, it was much slower before, the AdapterImageView sped it up slightly, but it's still way slower than the original piece of code! confused.com